# What is it called when you pass a question to a higher up

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Eg: I must **X** this to my manager

Comment: "Elevate" is often used, e.g. "We must elevate this matter to a higher level."

Comment: I think *escalate* is more common than *elevate*.

Answer (score 5):

You're making a [referral](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/referral) - *the act of directing someone to a different place or person for information, help, or action, often to a person or group with more knowledge or power*.

So the sentence would be:

I must refer this to my manager.

Comment: The archetypal term, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

How about **raise**? From M-W:

> **[raise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raise)**: to bring up for consideration or debate

Your example:

> I must **raise** this to my manager

**Elevate**, as suggested by @Chasly, is a similar possibility, but the definitions in neither M-W nor Lexico support it, despite his and my own experiences.